# How to find the voltage threshold at which diode switches states?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, electronics

The diode in the figure is described by its offset model: $U_{D0} = 0.6 V$ and $r_d = 0$. Knowing that $E_0 = 3.9 V$, find the voltage threshold $u_l$, at which the diode switches to its opposite state.
[image]

I've replaced the diode with its offset model and obtained the following equivalent circuit:
[image]

After applying KVL, I've obtained that $u_l = -u_D - i_DR$. Since $U_{D0}$ is greater than 0, I've deduced that the diode must be ON in this case, therefore $u_D = 0$, so $u_l = -i_DR$. The problem is I don't know how to find $i_D$ so I can calculate $u_l$. The answer for this problem should be, according to the book, $-4.5$ . Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: hint: 3.9+0.6 = 4.5

Comment: @hyportnex Does this mean that $u_D = E_0$ and $i_D * R = U_{D0}$ so $u_l = -(E_0 + U_{D0})?$